# XML file and dtd associated

Tags: javascript, xml, dtd

I've a problem with a simple xml file exercise.
This is the XML file called "Newfile.xml"

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="students.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE students SYSTEM "student.dtd">
  <student id="100026">
    <name>Joe Average</name>
    <age>21</age>
    <major>Biology</major>
    <results>
      <result course="Math 101" grade="C-"/>
      <result course="Biology 101" grade="C+"/>
      <result course="Statistics 101" grade="D"/>
    </results>
  </student>
  <student id="100078">
    <name>Jack Doe</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <major>Physics</major>
    <major>XML Science</major>
    <results>
      <result course="Math 101" grade="A"/>
      <result course="XML 101" grade="A-"/>
      <result course="Physics 101" grade="B+"/>
      <result course="XML 102" grade="A"/>
    </results>
  </student>
</students>
```

And this is the relative dtd file called "student.dtd" and placed in the same directory

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT students (student+)>

<!ELEMENT student (name,age,major,results)>
<!ATTLIST student id CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT major (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT results (result+)>


<!-- <!ELEMENT result (grade,course)> -->
<!ELEMENT result (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST result grade CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST result course CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

When i try to run Newfile.xml with Eclipse it say:
"Error line 14:
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

Where is the error?
Can you help me?

Comment: So, did you find my answer useful at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your XML is not well formed - you have the opening and closing tags for a `student` element, then the same again for another `student` element, and then you have the **closing tag** for a `students` element.

But you've got no opening tag for a `students` element.

Incidentally, you also have 2 `major` elements in the second `student` element, but your DTD specifies that only 1 `major` element is allowed.

Try the following, it is valid according to your DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="students.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE students SYSTEM "student.dtd">
<students>
  <student id="100026">
    <name>Joe Average</name>
    <age>21</age>
    <major>Biology</major>
    <results>
      <result course="Math 101" grade="C-"/>
      <result course="Biology 101" grade="C+"/>
      <result course="Statistics 101" grade="D"/>
    </results>
  </student>
  <student id="100078">
    <name>Jack Doe</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <major>Physics</major>
    <results>
      <result course="Math 101" grade="A"/>
      <result course="XML 101" grade="A-"/>
      <result course="Physics 101" grade="B+"/>
      <result course="XML 102" grade="A"/>
    </results>
  </student>
</students>
```